# UpdateData in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

**Language**: C++

**Development Environment**: Microsoft Visual C++

**Libraries Used**: MFC

**Problem**: I have created a preference configuration application. To the left is a list box with the "parent" categories of settings they can change, and when they click one, the settings they can change appear to the right of the list box, like in many large preference dialogs. I have all of my controls set up with DDX data exchanges (note: I have a cpp file for EACH sub-dialog/preference page), so I have all of the groundwork set.

Here's my issue. I'm having a hard time using UpdateData because I never actually call DoModal() on the preference boxes because they're children of the parent dialog container, and they are just bound to the picture control in the dialog. I perform a combination of setting focus and showing/hiding the sub-dialogs when the user clicks through the listbox.

When the user selects "Save These" he/she is presented with another dialog that allows them to check which specific preference panes they want to save (to generate XML configuration files). Obviously I need to scrape the dialog for their inputs, but when the program reaches the point in the code where it calls UpdateData, the program fails, because I'm calling UpdateData before calling DoModal().

Now I'm not really sure how to go about getting the values. It doesn't help either that I'm very new to MFC. So there's that. Anyhow, I would appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User experience could possibly be improved by using `CTabCtrl` which provides the kind of functionality you seem to be implementing.

In general you aren't meant to call `UpdateData` directly in most cases this is a framework mechanic called by `OnInitDialog` to load and `OnOK` to save for modal dialogs. This is not loading and saving in the sense you might be thinking. What it does is load the control values from the resource or member variables in `OnInitDialog` then when the user clicks OK it validates and saves the values of the controls on the dialog into the member variables. This is the mechanic that allows you to display previous values when reopening the dialog as well as getting the values out after they close it.

You can look into `CArchive` and serializing your dialogs but I would suggest writing your own saving/loading framework especially if dealing with XML configuration files.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid having to partially re-do the UI if I can. I've tried just using OnOK() because I know that it calls UpdateData, but because of the way my application works, it doesn't like what I'm trying to do. Basically I have a "Save All" button and a "Save These" button, which specify which sub-dialogs are saved. SaveThese pops up a dialog with check boxes so they can specify which panes to save, and it's on the dismissal (OnOK) of this chooser that I want to save the information...which requires getting all of the values. I tried just calling OnOK on the sub-dialog to no avail.

Comment: Without seeing the code it sounds like you need a data structure for each pane and an interface allowing you to have a collection of these data structures which can be used to save/load from your unrelated dialog. I'm assuming these panes are modeless so an interface allowing you to have a collection of pane pointers you can cycle through would also help make things easier.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to research that...I'm not sure what you mean by an interface for each pane. I'm fairly new to visual-c++ and MFC, so it's been a challenge getting this thing as far as it is. Any suggestions? I don't want to take up too much of your time...

Comment: Basically in C++ you can use a pure virtual base class as an interface. Then a collection of interface class pointers can be used to maintain derived concrete types. Your interface may be as simple as defining a Save and Load method which the derived panes must implement. Then you could easily make an object which can save or load all letting polymorphism take care of how for each pane. For a more advanced or robust version of this design google the "visitor pattern".

Answer (score 3):

Just before you show one of your sub-dialogs, you should call its `UpdateData(FALSE)` function to populate its controls. This should be in the OnInitDialog of the outer dialog, and also in the code that switches categories. Just before switching away from a sub-dialog (either from category change or OnOK) you should call `UpdateData(TRUE)` to pull the changes back from the sub-dialog; do not allow the category to be changed or the dialog to be closed if UpdateData returns FALSE.

Comment: I have a form with two text fields T1 and T2. User changes T1. T2 has a `...` button at its right, that opens a modal dialog and modifies T2. User goes to `...` and clicks OK. T2 needs to be updated. After assigning the new value to T2 associated variable, I can not do `Updatedata(FALSE)` because it makes the T1 user-made change to disappear. I see two approaches to solve the problem. 1: Call `T2->SetWindowText(new_text);` 2: Declare a `CDataExchange dx(this, FALSE);` variable and do `DDX_Text` only for T2. What is the best approach?

Comment: @sergiol I assume T1 is part of the parent dialog, correct? This answer is about calling `UpdateData` on the child dialog for T2 which shouldn't affect T1. The code that called the child dialog is then responsible for copying the data from that dialog into the text control.